# Adding new file wizard in an eclipse application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, wizard

I am completely new to plugin development. I want to add almost an exact new project wizard of an eclipse application and modify it to my requirements.

I tried using the existing extension **org.eclipse.ui.newWizards** to generate a new wizard but it adds a new file in an already existing project and not a new project as a whole.

```
    ContainerSelectionDialog dialog = new ContainerSelectionDialog(
            getShell(), ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(), true,
            "Select new file container");
    if (dialog.open() == ContainerSelectionDialog.OK) {
        Object[] result = dialog.getResult();
        if (result.length == 1) {
            containerText.setText(((Path) result[0]).toString());
        }
```

Also, is there any way to export an already existing wizard and then put it back edited?

Comment: If  you want to create a new project you create a new wizard using a wizard extending `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewProjectResourceWizard`

Comment: You don't copy the source code for things like this. You extend the existing class that is already in Eclipse by adding a dependency on the appropriate plugin. This is far too broad for StackOverflow, read some tutorials on Eclipse RCPs - [vogella.com](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipse.html) is a good site.